# Can you use excel lookup table in SQL database pull?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Is there a way to import a lookup table of account numbers from excel and only pull results from the database that match the account numbers listed in the excel lookup table? My lookup table contains thousands of account numbers so I can't manually type in the results that I want to filter for. I am using Microsoft SQL server studio to pull data from a SQL server database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from SSMS in the object explorer you can right click on the database Tasks-->Import Data. From there you can use the UI to import the spreadsheet as a table in your database.

Comment: what if I don't have permission to write to the database, i.e. read only access?

Comment: Ask your DBA or IT staff for help. Yes, it is possible but it does require certain permissions (and skills) to access (or import) this information from your database server. Alternatively, you could pull that information into excel and then write code in your spreadsheet to filter or adjust the data as needed.

Comment: Unfortunately the data has more rows than excel can handle and that is why I would like to filter the data in the code first. I think I will use Python to filter the data by reading an excel file, creating a dataframe based on that excel file, and matching against that dataframe.